# What is YARN (Hadoop) - very simple example

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Hadoop and trying to understand it. I found a nice explanation
of HDFS and MapReduce with very simple examples (see below). But I cannot
google any similar simple example for YARN. **Could someone please explain it
(like for a layman)?**

[HDFS](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/hadoop/hdfs)

> Think of a file that contains the phone numbers for everyone in the United
>   States; the people with a last name starting with A might be stored on server
>   1, B on server 2, and so on.
>
> In a Hadoop world, pieces of this phonebook would be stored across the cluster,
>   and to reconstruct the entire phonebook, your program would need the blocks
>   from every server in the cluster. To achieve availability as components fail,
>   HDFS replicates these smaller pieces onto two additional servers by default.
>   (This redundancy can be increased or decreased on a per-file basis or for a
>   whole environment; for example, a development Hadoop cluster typically doesn’t
>   need any data redundancy.) This redundancy offers multiple benefits, the most
>   obvious being higher availability.
>
> In addition, this redundancy allows the Hadoop cluster to break work up into
>   smaller chunks and run those jobs on all the servers in the cluster for better
>   scalability. Finally, you get the benefit of data locality, which is critical
>   when working with large data sets. We detail these important benefits later in
>   this chapter.

[MapReduce](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/hadoop/mapreduce)

> Let’s look at a simple example. Assume you have five files, and each file
>   contains two columns (a key and a value in Hadoop terms) that represent a city
>   and the corresponding temperature recorded in that city for the various
>   measurement days. Of course we’ve made this example very simple so it’s easy to
>   follow. You can imagine that a real application won’t be quite so simple, as
>   it’s likely to contain millions or even billions of rows, and they might not be
>   neatly formatted rows at all; in fact, no matter how big or small the amount of
>   data you need to analyze, the key principles we’re covering here remain the
>   same. Either way, in this example, city is the key and temperature is the
>   value.
>
> Toronto, 20
>   Whitby, 25
>   New York, 22
>   Rome, 32
>   Toronto, 4
>   Rome, 33
>   New York, 18
>
> Out of all the data we have collected, we want to find the maximum temperature
>   for each city across all of the data files (note that each file might have the
>   same city represented multiple times). Using the MapReduce framework, we can
>   break this down into five map tasks, where each mapper works on one of the five
>   files and the mapper task goes through the data and returns the maximum
>   temperature for each city. For example, the results produced from one mapper
>   task for the data above would look like this:
>
> (Toronto, 20) (Whitby, 25) (New York, 22) (Rome, 33)
>
> Let’s assume the other four mapper tasks (working on the other four files not
>   shown here) produced the following intermediate results:
>
> (Toronto, 18) (Whitby, 27) (New York, 32) (Rome, 37)(Toronto, 32) (Whitby, 20)
>   (New York, 33) (Rome, 38)(Toronto, 22) (Whitby, 19) (New York, 20) (Rome,
>   31)(Toronto, 31) (Whitby, 22) (New York, 19) (Rome, 30)
>
> All five of these output streams would be fed into the reduce tasks, which
>   combine the input results and output a single value for each city, producing a
>   final result set as follows:
>
> (Toronto, 32) (Whitby, 27) (New York, 33) (Rome, 38)
>
> As an analogy, you can think of map and reduce tasks as the way a census was
>   conducted in Roman times, where the census bureau would dispatch its people to
>   each city in the empire. Each census taker in each city would be tasked to
>   count the number of people in that city and then return their results to the
>   capital city.
>
> There, the results from each city would be reduced to a single count (sum of
>   all cities) to determine the overall population of the empire. This mapping of
>   people to cities, in parallel, and then combining the results (reducing) is
>   much more efficient than sending a single person to count every person in the
>   empire in a serial fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have 4 machines each with 4GB of RAM and dual core CPUs.
You can present YARN to an application able to distribute and parallelize workloads, such as MapReduce, and YARN will respond that it is able to accept 16GB of application workload on 8 CPU cores.

Not all nodes need to be the same, some can be used with GPU resources or higher memory throughput, but you'll always be limited by the smallest node in the group for any single running application... And the framework decides which node your code is deployed to based on resources available, not you. When a NodeManager is combined with an HDFS datanode (they're running on the same machine) your code attempting to read a file, will be attempted to be ran by that machine containing parts of the files you need.

Basically, divide your storage into small chucks (HDFS), provide a way to read those chunks into complete files (MapReduce), and use some processing engine to distribute that operation fairly, or greedily into resource pools (YARN's Fair Scheduler or Capacity Scheduler)